# ASP.net Core eager loading, let included object be null

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-core, null, entity-framework-core, eager-loading

I am getting all customers and including their linked operator.
The only catch is a customer can exist without an operator. 
The problem I am having is when i try include the operator any customer that doesn't have a linked operator is not retrieved is there a way to still retrieve all my customers and if thy do not have an operator just have the operator object within the customer be null?

-get all customers method

```
public List<Customer> GetAllWithRelations()
    {
        return Context.Set<Customer>()
            .Include(cp => cp.Operator).ToList();
    }
```

-Cusomer object

```
public class Customer
{
    public int Id { get; set; }

    public string Name { get; set; }        

    public int? OperatorId { get; set; }

    [ForeignKey("OperatorId")]
    public virtual Operator Operator { get; set; }
}
```

-Operator Object

```
public class Operator
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Although you did not specify a tag for this, by using the `.Include` I'm guessing it's a `EntityFramework Core` linq which is breaking.

I've came across the same case on EF whenever the relationship is not set to allow nulls. So, for instance, your mapping might be explicitly setting it to be required or somehow you're not setting it and EF defaults are stablishing a required map between `Customer` and `Operator`.

Just set it to optional wherever you're building your model mappings and you'll get the desired behavior.
See: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/modeling/required-optional